# Is there a way to only sum the cells in column 2 if data in column 1 is greater than zero?

Tags: excel

```
Column 1.    Column 2

0.           14
20.          25
14.          12
```

Total of column 2 is 51 which means employees have a goal of selling 51 products.

Total of column 1 is 34 sales.

I need to calculate what the daily sales goal would be and in the case above the daily goal would not be 51, it would be 37 as the first agent had the day off.

What would the excel formula be?

I’m a novice, tried sumif and sumifs but possibly got the formula wrong.

Comment: The question didn’t post the rows & columns as I listed them

Comment: Next time please include your attempts. Show the formulae you tried and in what way they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in A2-B4, the formula would be:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A4, ">0", B2:B4)
```

The `SUMIF` function takes the arguments `range, criteria[, sum_range]` (`[]` means optional). The sum is taken if the given `criteria` matches on the currently relevant cell of the `range`, and if yes, the relevant cell of either `sum_range`, if given, or `range` is taken into the sum.

Here we specify that we want to sum the values of the `sum_range` `B2:B4` but only if the corresponding cell in the `range` `A2:A4` matches the `criteria` of being `>0`.

See also [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

Answer (score 1):

And here is a different approach:

[image]

```
SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A4>0,1,0),B2:B4)
```

Not bad for a Saturday afternoon :)

Answer (score 0):

The SUMIF() function is what you want: =SUMIF(A1:A3,">0",B1:B3)

The first input is the range to apply the criteria to, the second is your criteria, and the third is the range to be summed.

More info on this function can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: This answer is no different from the accepted one.